# I can't connect java in eclipse to SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

When running my code, I get the following error:

> Error de conexi�n: Error de inicio de sesi�n del usuario ''.
> ClientConnectionId:7d721444-7622-4951-a321-3607a1c7167a

this is the code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pokemon {
    /*Esto guarda en una variable local de tipo String llamado url
    la e indica que se esta utilizando SQL Server en la misma máquina 
    en la que se está ejecutando el programa, en el puerto 3003, y que la base de 
    datos que se está utilizando se llama "pokemondb"
    El trusted server es para que no tire  error de certificado*/
     private static final String driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DriverJDBCVersion";
      private static final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3003;databaseName=pokemondb;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True";
    //jbd es una api de Java que permite establecer conexion de Java con SQl
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection con=conexion();
        Scanner escaner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean salir = false;//bandera para salir del menu
        int opcion; //Guardaremos la opcion del usuario
        do
        {
            System.out.println("-------- Menu Principal--------");
            System.out.println("1 Mostrar todos los pokemons ");
            System.out.println("2 Actualizar nombre del pokemon por su numero de la Pokedex ");
            System.out.println("3 Borrar pokemon ");
            System.out.println("4 Insertar nuevo pokemon ");
            System.out.println("5 Mostrar todos los movimientos(incluyendo MT y MO) que puede apreder un pokemon");
            System.out.println("6 Filtrar los pokemon por tipos ");
            System.out.println("7 Mostrar el número de movimientos de cada tipo ");
            System.out.println("8 Salir ");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion");
            opcion=escaner.nextInt();
            switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                mostrarPokemon();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Inserte el numero de la Pokedex");
                int id=escaner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("INTRODUZCA EL NUEVO NOMBRE DEL POKEMON");
                String nombre=escaner.toString();
                actualizarPokemon(id,nombre );
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Inserte el numero de la Pokedex");
                int id1=escaner.nextInt();
                borrarPokemon(id1);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("INTRODUZCA EL NOMBRE DEL NUEVO POKEMON");
                String nombre1=escaner.toString();
                System.out.println("INTRODUZCA EL PESO DEL POKEMON");
                Float peso=escaner.nextFloat();
                System.out.println("INTRODUZCA LA ALTURA DEL NUEVO POKEMON");
                Float altura=escaner.nextFloat();
                insertarPokemon(nombre1, peso, altura);
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Introduce el numero de la pokedex");
                int n=escaner.nextInt();
                mostrarMovimiento(n);
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Introduce un tipo para filtrarlo");
                String tipo=escaner.toString();
                filtrarTipo(tipo);
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("Introduce un tipo");
                String tipo2=escaner.toString();
                filtrarMovimiento(tipo2);
                break;
            case 8:
                salir=true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }while(!salir);//mientras salir no sea verdadero
        escaner.close();
    }
        public static void mostrarPokemon() throws SQLException{
            Connection con=conexion();
            String pokedex = "SELECT NUMERO_POKEDEX,NOMBRE  FROM Pokemon";
            PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement(pokedex);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){//mientras que en la consulta de rs se obtengra una respuesta
                System.out.println(rs);//imprima la consulta de rs
            }
            
            
        }
        public static String actualizarPokemon(int id, String nombre) throws SQLException{
            Connection con=conexion();
            String consulta = "update Pokemon set NOMBRE=?  where NUMERO_POKEDEX=?";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setString(1, nombre);//establece el nombre del parametro nombre
            ps.setInt(2, id);//establece el valor del parametro NUMERO_POKEDEX
            return "El nombre del pokemon con id " + id + " ha sido actualizado a " + nombre;
        }
        public static String borrarPokemon(int id) throws SQLException{
            Connection con=conexion();
            String consulta="delete  from Pokemon where NUMERO_POKEDEX= ?";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            return "El pokemon con numero "+id+" has sido eliminado";
        }
        public static void insertarPokemon(String nombre,double peso, double altura) throws SQLException{
            Connection con=conexion();
             String consulta = "INSERT INTO Pokemon(NOMBRE, PESO, ALTURA) VALUES (?,?,?)";
             PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
             ps.setString(1,nombre);
             ps.setDouble(2,peso);
             ps.setDouble(3,altura);
             String n = "SELECT NUMERO_POKEDEX FROM Pokemon WHERE NOMBRE=?";
             PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement(n);
             ps1.setString(1,nombre);
             ResultSet rs=ps1.executeQuery();
             while(rs.next()) {
                 System.out.println("Se ha insertado el nuevo pokemon con nombre "+nombre+" y numero de la pokedex "+rs.getInt("Pokemon.NUMERO_POKEDEX"));
             }
               
        }
        private static void mostrarMovimiento(int n) throws SQLException{
            Connection con=conexion();
            String consulta="select p.NUMERO_POKEDEX,p.NOMBRE,m.NOMBRE from Pokemon p join Pokemon_Movimiento_Forma pmf on p.NUMERO_POKEDEX=pmf.NUMERO_POKEDEX  join Movimiento m on pmf.ID_MOVIMIENTO=m.ID_MOVIMIENTO  where p.NUMERO_POKEDEX=?";             
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setInt(1, n);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs);
            }
    }
        private static void filtrarTipo(String t) throws SQLException {
            Connection con=conexion();
            String consulta="select p.NUMERO_POKEDEX,p.NOMBRE,p.PESO,p.ALTURA,t.nombre from pokemon p join Pokemon_Tipo pt on p.NUMERO_POKEDEX=pt.NUMERO_POKEDEX join Tipo t on pt.ID_TIPO=t.ID_TIPO  where t.nombre=?;";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setString(1,t);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs);
            }
        }
        private static void filtrarMovimiento(String t) throws SQLException {
            Connection con=conexion();
            String consulta="select t.nombre, count(t.nombre) AS \"Numeros de movimiento\" from Movimiento m join Tipo t on m.ID_TIPO=t.ID_TIPO where t.nombre=? group by t.nombre";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setString(1,t);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs);
            }
        }   
          public static Connection conexion()  {
                Connection con=null;
                try {
                    Class.forName(driver);
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");/*establece una conexión con la base de datos a través de JDBC (Java Database Connectivity), 
                    //utilizando la URL de conexión especificada.DriverManager es una clase del paquete java.sql 
                    que se encarga de cargar y registrar el controlador JDBC apropiado, y devolver una instancia de Connection 
                    que representa una conexión con la base de datos.*/
                    System.out.println("Conexión exitosa");
                    
                } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error de conexión: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
                return con;             
          }
        }
```

I'm using the Windows login method and the port is 3003
What do I have to change to make my code work?

I am trying to establish a connection between java and the SQL Server pokemondb database.
When I run the code I get this:

> Error de conexi�n: Error de inicio de sesi�n del usuario ''.
> ClientConnectionId:7d721444-7622-4951-a321-3607a1c7167a

Comment: Error message simply google translated to English says "Connection error: User login error", and you are using `con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","")` to connect to the DB, where username & password are blank. So, the error could be related to that. Are you sure blank username with blank password will be able to connect to the DB?  Shouldn't the username be `sa` - if it is default installation, and its default password would also be there.

Comment: You should also not limit information available to you about the error. `ex.printStackTrace()` is what you want

Comment: try DriverManager.getConnection(url);